# How to deploy spree application using capistrano

Tags: amazon-ec2, capistrano, spree

I am asking this question because the deployment steps I had been using for other application doesn't seem to work for spree application.

Please suggest me if i am missing something:

On Development Mac I run following commands & I can see the store
working on localhost:3000:

```
brew install imagemagick

$ gem install rmagick

$  rails new store
```

- put spree in gem file

  $  bundle

  ```
  $ rails g spree:site

  $ rake db:bootstrap
  ```

Using capistrano to deploy the app to http://passionate4.net/  I can
following commands:

```
$ cap deploy:setup
$ cap deploy:cold
$ cap deploy
```

If you look at the http://passionate4.net/ I am getting some error.

Here is how the production.log look like

```
ubuntu@ip-10-166-185-18:/var/www/spree_store/current/log$ cat production.log
Migrating to CreatePosts (20111113203521)
```

According to above log information, when I looked into the mysql database, I was unable to find the Create Posts table.

How should i go about this problem?

---

FYI: It works perfect on localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to follow these steps here https://github.com/spree/spree

Also, study this documentation on Spree here http://guides.spreecommerce.com/logic_customization.html

On capistrano, follow this documentation: http://capitate.rubyforge.org/recipes/deploy.html#deploy:cold